# Why is CORS needed for localhost?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, localhost, cors

There's probably an answer already on stackoverflow that I'm missing, sorry in advance for that, I just can't find it.

I have a small TCP server running on my localhost that, for security reasons, will not support CORS.

My question is, if CORS is for cross-domain protection, why is it being requested when I have a page on `http://localhost/` request a connection to `http://localhost:xxxx`

I know I can turn off the security in my browser, but Im trying to understand why localhost to localhost connections are being treated as cross-origin.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `localhost` (port 80) is a different host than `localhost:8000`.

See [RFC 6454, Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-5):

> ```
>   If the two origins are scheme/host/port triples, the two origins
>   are the same if, and only if, they have identical schemes, hosts,
>   and ports.
> ```

Comment: That is bloody annoying...and makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Same-origin Policy**

The same-origin policy permits scripts running in a browser to only make requests to pages on the same domain. This means that requests must have the ***same URI scheme, hostname, and port number.*** [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) post on the Mozilla Developer Network clearly defines the definition of an origin and when requests result in failure. If you send a request from `http://www.example.com/,` the following types of requests result in failure.

```
https://www.example.com/ – Different protocol (or URI scheme).
http://www.example.com:8080/myUrl – Different port (since HTTP requests run on port 80 by default).
http://www.myotherexample.com/ – Different domain.
http://example.com/ – Treated as a different domain as it requires the exact match (Notice there is no www.).
```

For more information refer to [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/working-around-origin-policy/)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure how I missed that link.